# Android Popup help - not appearing

Tags: android, popup, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to load a popup window that contains an edittext and a datepicker.

I have included my code below.

Basically the initial window is closed as expected, but my pop up doesn't appear?

I have checked the xml call and the id is correct, no errors and for some reason my logcat in eclipse has stopped working but thats a different issue!

Hopefully someone can tell me what I have missed and / or doing wrong? I am new to android programming so please ignore my ignorance if it is something simple!

```
package com.zelphe.zelpheapp;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.zelphe.zelpheapp.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.zelphe.zelpheapp.library.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{

    Button btnLogin;
    Button Btnregister;
    Button passreset;
    EditText inputEmail, inputName, inputPassword;
    DatePicker inputDOB;
    private TextView loginErrorMsg;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_REGISTER = "doRegister";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


    Button btnReg;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_test);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);

        //loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginErrorMsg);



/**
 * Login button click event
 * A Toast is set to alert when the Email and Password field is empty
 **/
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    NetAsync(view);
                }
                else if ( ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if ( ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Email field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Email and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


/**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
 **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(false);
            nDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
        **/
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){



            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessLogin().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
     **/
    private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();


            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
               if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading User Space");
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                        /**
                         * Clear all previous data in SQlite database.
                         **/
                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                       /**
                        *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
                        **/
                        Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(upanel);
                        /**
                         * Close Login Screen
                         **/
                        finish();
                    }else if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 2)
                    {


                         pDialog.dismiss();
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                 "Incorrect Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        initiatePopupWindow();



                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }



        private PopupWindow pwindo;

        private void initiatePopupWindow() 
        { 
            try 
                { 
                    // We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater 
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) LoginActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register,(ViewGroup)

                    findViewById(R.id.popup_element)); 
                    pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 350, 350, true); 
                    pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                    btnReg = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnReg); 
                    btnReg.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) reguser);

                } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        }
        private OnClickListener reguser = new OnClickListener() 
        { 


            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
                inputDOB = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dob);

                if (  ( !inputName.getText().toString().equals("")) &&
                        ( getAge(inputDOB.getDayOfMonth(), inputDOB.getMonth(), inputDOB.getYear()) > 15) )
                {
                    //register user
                }
                else if ( ( inputName.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (( getAge(inputDOB.getDayOfMonth(), inputDOB.getMonth(), inputDOB.getYear()) < 16) )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You must be at least 16 to use this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            } 
        };


    }

    public int getAge (int _year, int _month, int _day) {

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int y, m, d, a;         

        y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        cal.set(_year, _month, _day);
        a = y - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if ((m < cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                        || ((m == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) && (d < cal
                                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
                --a;
        }
        if(a < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age < 0");
        return a;
}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarassingly enough, there is no issue with the popup, I had an error further up in my code, doh!